# Retrieve Option data from Select

Tags: jquery

I have pulldown menu defined like this:

```
<select id="select_command" ><option data-syntax="blabla"></option></select>
```

How can I retrieve the `data-syntax` of the currently selected option upon clicking some button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#some_button').on('click', function() {
    var syntax = $('#select_command :selected').data('syntax');
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var sel=$('option').filter(':selected').data('syntax');
    alert(sel);
});
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. `.is()` method returns a boolean value, it doesn't work as an element filter.

Comment: `.filter()` is OK, however in your example it is rather excessive to use additional filtering if all could be done in a single selector.